# Broken libgcc1 dependency in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I've updated to Ubuntu 20.04 recently and I'm currently not able to install any new fixes because there is a broken dependency with `libgcc1`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgcc1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  blender-data fonts-dejavu g++-7 gcc-9-base:i386 gdal-data gir1.2-mutter-2 ibverbs-providers libaec0 libargon2-0 libarmadillo8 libarmadillo9 libarpack2 libavcodec57 libavdevice57 libavfilter6
  libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libbind9-160 libblosc1 libboost-date-time1.65.1 libboost-filesystem1.65.1 libboost-iostreams1.65.1 libboost-locale1.65.1 libboost-regex1.65.1
  libboost-system1.65.1 libboost-thread1.65.1 libcaf-openmpi-3 libcamel-1.2-61 libcdio17 libcfitsio8 libcharls1 libcharls2 libcoarrays-openmpi-dev libcrystalhd3 libcue1 libdap25 libdapclient6v5
  libdcmtk14 libdns-export1100 libdns1100 libdouble-conversion1 libdvdread4 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libebur128-1 libecal-1.2-19 libedataserver-1.2-23 libepsilon1 libevent-2.1-6 libevent-core-2.1-7
  libevent-dev libevent-extra-2.1-7 libevent-openssl-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libexiv2-14 libfabric1 libffi6:i386 libfluidsynth1 libfreexl1 libfyba0 libgconf2.0-cil libgdbm5 libgdcm2.8 libgdcm3.0
  libgegl-0.3-0 libgeos-3.6.2 libgeos-3.8.0 libgeos-c1v5 libgeotiff2 libgeotiff5 libgfortran4 libgl2ps1.4 libglew2.0 libglew2.1 libgmime-3.0-0 libgnome-desktop-3-17 libgpm2:i386
  libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12 libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libgspell-1-1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 libgweather-3-15 libhdf4-0-alt libhdf5-103 libhdf5-openmpi-103 libhogweed4 libhunspell-1.6-0 libhwloc-dev
  libhwloc-plugins libhwloc15 libibverbs-dev libibverbs1 libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libiptc0 libirs160 libisc-export169 libisc169 libisccc160 libisccfg160 libisl19 libjemalloc1 libjemalloc2 libjson-c3
  libkmlbase1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 liblept5 liblog4cplus-1.1-9 liblouis14 liblouisutdml8 liblwres160 libmagick++-6.q16-7 libminiupnpc10 libminizip1 libmlt++3 libmlt-data libmlt6 libmovit8
  libmozjs-52-0 libmutter-2-0 libmysofa0 libmysqlclient20 libncurses5:i386 libncursesw5:i386 libnetcdf-c++4 libnetcdf15 libnettle6 libnl-3-dev libnl-route-3-dev libnss-myhostname libntfs-3g88 libnuma-dev
  libodbc1 libogdi3.2 libopencolorio1v5 libopencv-core3.2 libopencv-core4.2 libopencv-dnn4.2 libopencv-flann4.2 libopencv-imgproc3.2 libopencv-imgproc4.2 libopencv-ml3.2 libopencv-ml4.2
  libopencv-photo4.2 libopencv-video3.2 libopencv-viz4.2 libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi3 libopenshot14 libopenvdb5.0 libopenvdb6.2 liborcus-0.13-0 libosdcpu3.4.0 libosdgpu3.4.0 libperl5.26 libplymouth4
  libpmix2 libpoppler73 libpostproc54 libpq5 libprocps6 libproj12 libproj15 libprotobuf10 libpsm-infinipath1 libpsm2-2 libpython3.6 libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libqgsttools-p1 libqhull7
  libqpdf21 libraw16 librdmacm1 libreadline7 libreoffice-style-galaxy librtaudio6 libsane1 libsocket++1 libspatialite7 libspnav0 libsquish0 libstdc++-7-dev libsuperlu5 libswresample2 libswscale4 libsz2
  libtbb2 libtesseract4 libtiff5-dev libtinfo5:i386 libtinyxml2.6.2v5 liburiparser1 libusbmuxd4 libvpx5 libvtk6.3 libwireshark11 libwiretap8 libwscodecs2 libwsutil9 libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libx264-152
  libx265-146 libxerces-c3.2 libxnvctrl0 libyaml-cpp0.5v5 libyaml-cpp0.6 linux-image-4.4.0-193-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-193-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-193-generic nplan odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 openmpi-bin openmpi-common proj-bin proj-data python-asn1crypto python-fasteners python-monotonic python3-asn1crypto python3-mlt python3-numpy python3-oauth python3-zope.interface
  python3.6 python3.6-minimal qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtwebkit vorbisgain wireshark-gtk x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgcc1
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/41.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.4 kB disk space will be freed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 package libgcc1:amd64 (1:10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) with field 'Multi-Arch: no' is not co-installable with libgcc1 which has multiple installed instances
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

---

Output of `apt-cache policy libgcc1`:

```
libgcc1:
  Installed: 1:9.2.1-17ubuntu1~14.01
  Candidate: 1:10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
  Version table:
     1:10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
     1:10-20200411-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 1:9.2.1-17ubuntu1~14.01 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Hey Tianico! Let's look into the APT log to analyse the situation. Open your terminal, paste this: `gedit /var/log/apt/history.log` and press Enter. Copy the contents of the file, paste it in a pastebin (like https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and share the link of the pastebin. Also, paste the output of `apt-cache policy libgcc1` in your question (use the [edit] feature to edit your question). If you're replying to my comment, don't forget to tag me like this: @technastic_tc

Comment: Hello @technastic_tc, thanks for your reply. Please find below the output of the two commands: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mp4HWYbRR5/ and https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mZj8NcshkB/

Comment: Great, I tried it out and it solved the issues. Thanks a lot @BeastOfCaerbannog

Answer (score 3):

From your output it seems that you have an older version of `libgcc1` installed (`1:9.2.1-17ubuntu1~14.01`), which conflicts with the installation of the new version (`1:10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04`).

So, uninstall `libgcc1` and install it again using:

```
sudo apt purge libgcc1 && sudo apt install libgcc1
```

Thanks [@technastic_tc](https://askubuntu.com/users/1103140/technastic-tc) for requesting and adding the necessary info in the question.

Comment: You're welcome BeastOfCaerbannog! Thanks for answering the question :)